# clean VS 2015 Enterprise + Xamarin Install: error: NuGet Package restore failed for project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

Hello i have a clean Installation of VS2015 Enterprise + Xamarin.

Then just start a New Projekt (Xamarin Forms Portable) add a Button and want to test on Android Emu.

Then i get the Following 5 Errors and i don't know, how to solved it.

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTnqE.png)

[start Projekt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrjvQ.gif)

Comment: Same problem here, using the Caliburn.Micro Hello.Forms sample app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restore the NuGet packages manually. Navigate to Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution. If you see the button "Restore packages," click it. Make sure the packages are up to date. Furthermore, check your Android SDK is up to date. Navigate to Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager.

Comment: no button "Restore packages", nuget packages are up to date. Android sdk install all updates. still don't work
thx for help

Comment: @evgen1j that means you probably use a very old NuGet manager. Try to use Tools|Extensions and Updates to update to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the UWP project, you can delete it or try yo install this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/2.0.0.6482

For the other errors, install this Nuget Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter/23.0.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a long shot but I had similar problems when restoring packages in Visual Studio 2015, and that was caused by a custom nuget server I added to sources (with authetication). Try temporary disable any of these if you got any, in the Tools -> Options -> NuGet package manager

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- Remove the reference of Xamarin Forms portable library from your WinSetupDemo.UWP project, I believe Xamarin forms doesn't support UWP unless you use [Xamarin Forms v2.1 and above](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/)
- Make sure that the Android Support Library is installed correctly, search for it in the Xamarin components store and follow the setup instructions, make sure it installs correctly, one of the reasons it fails is that your directory hiererchy is too deep so that file names become too long, if this is the case, try installing your Android SDK at a top level directory such as C:\Android